# trying to add a new entry in windows 10 hosts file

Tags: windows-10, hosts

just tried to add a new entry to my windows hosts file so that instead of using this:

```
  http://localhost:8085/
```

to launch my wordpress site, I can just do something like this:

```
  http://widget.local/
```

This is what my c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1::8085 widget.local
localhost::8085 widget.local
```

Rebooted my machine after making the change. But widget.local doesn't work.

I also tried this:

```
127.0.0.1:8085 widget.local
localhost:8085 widget.local
```

Should I be able to do this? If so, can you tell me what I've done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the port from the hosts file, then maybe look into `netsh interface portproxy` as a way to redirect port 80 for example to 8085.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Should I be able to do this?

No. Host files do not contain port numbers.

> The hosts file contains lines of text consisting of an IP address in the first text field followed by one or more host names. Each field is separated by white space – tabs are often preferred for historical reasons, but spaces are also used. Comment lines may be included; they are indicated by an octothorpe (#) in the first position of such lines.

Source: [hosts (file) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#File_content)

Comment: kk so then widgets.local:8085  is what i'll have to shoot for eh?  Will update my hosts and reboot and retry

Comment: Sigh. No. host files do not contain port numbers **anywhere**. You need to find another approach to solve your problem